# How can I format text as code in Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: formatting, inbox-by-gmail

I sent an email today (or wanted to) from [Inbox by Gmail](http://inbox.google.com) and was disappointed at the apparent lack of ability to format text as code when compiling an email:

> [image]

How can I format text as code (or simply in any different font, for that matter) with Inbox by Gmail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install the [Markdown Here](http://markdown-here.com/) extension [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-here/elifhakcjgalahccnjkneoccemfahfoa) and write the code in markdown format in the email compose window.

You can either write the code with a four-space indent:

```
    this is
    some code
```

Or with the triple backtick format:

````
```
this is
some code
```
````

Then, to turn the markdown code into a properly formatted email, activate the extension by right-clicking and selecting Markdown Toggle from the menu, clicking the extension button next to the address bar, or using the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>.

Before and after screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you input something that looks like a web address in the code (say `foo.bar.baz.edu` or `/afs/spam.eggs.edu/usr/staff/qwerty`), will Inbox turn it into a link anyway after you click "Send", or will it leave it in plain text as it should?

Comment: Answer to self: yes it will turn them into links even though it shouldn't.

Comment: @arekolek are you sure it was converted to a link by the sending client rather than the viewing client? Remember a lot of clients will display plain-text as links.

Answer (score 3):

This is now easy to do, it seems to have been added a few weeks ago:

[image]

Comment: This suffers from the fact that Inbox doesn't treat it as pre-formatted text, so it will for example turn text into a link when it thinks it encounters one.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t (just yet, I think, currently being a work-in-progress type of product). There is no such option at the moment. The [help page](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067585?hl=en&ref_topic=6067575) only lists the bold, italic and underline options for the text (under *Format text*).

(I don’t have Inbox, so I can’t test this, but you could try pasting a formatted text from a different source.)